# A problem in polynomials to show that $a_{n−1}$ and $a_n$ must be coprime

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, polynomials

Let P(x) = $a_0x^n$ + · · · + $a_{n−1}x$ + $a_n$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients. Suppose the
equation P(x) = 0 has n distinct integer roots which are pairwisely coprime. Then prove
that $a_{n−1}$ and $a_n$ must be coprime.

This was asked in an examination and I couldn't solve it.
Please solve this problem.

Can anyone solve it...I hope people can see my post

Comment: You need $a_0=\pm 1$ - else take eg $4x^2-20x+24$ which has roots $x=2,3$.  Indeed if $|a_0|\gt 1$ then $a_0$ has to be a factor of all the coefficients if all the roots are to be integers. Have you heard of Vieta?

Comment: Yesssss...i know Vieta theorem Well

Comment: Can you write your hints in more arranged manner... How to start off and then how to proceed... It helps me

Comment: Mathtome, welcome to the site. Please take a look at [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619). You may want to adjust your approach a bit.

Comment: I would suggest that you write out the Vieta forms (expansions in terms of the roots) of $a_n$ and $a_{n-1}$ for say $n=2,3,4$ and you may see what is going on here. See which terms in each expression are divisible by a particular root.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** Embarrassingly, I overlooked the concept behind Mark Bennet's comment.  This response therefore assumes that $a_0 = \pm 1.$

Hint

First, see [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas).

Then, assume that $p$ is a prime number that divides both $a_n$ and $a_{(n-1)}.$

This means that $p$ divides some root of the equation.  This means that $p$ divides every term that comprises $a_{(n-1)}$ but one term.  What about this outstanding term.  Can $p$ also divide this outstanding term?

Comment: Can you please help me identify which is the outstanding Term?I can understand you are reaching a contradiction

Comment: @Mathtome assume that $p$ divides root $r$.  All but one of the terms that sum to $a_{(n-1)}$ have $r$ as a factor.